# How to get facebook name of user who left comment

Tags: php, facebook

Newbie here, I'm trying to get facebook name of user who left comment on my facebook page post but its not working. I'm using graph API v2.6. Here is my code:

```
$data = $this->check_file_get_contents($this->graph_api.$object_id.'/comments?
fields=from,name&access_token='.$access_token);
//$data = $this->check_file_get_contents($this->graph_api.$object_id.'/&access_token='.$access_token);

$res = json_decode($data);
$uname = $res->name;
echo $uname;
```

Any idea of what could be wrong here? Little guidance would be very helpful. What did I miss?

The $object_id is the Post ID. This is the output from graph api:

```
{
"data": [
{
  "from": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "id": "932242153456808"
  },
  "id": "585601208257495_620658141418468"
},
{
  "from": {
    "name": "Jason King",
    "id": "10153078961444510"
  },
  "id": "585601208257495_622535501230732"
},
{
  "from": {
    "name": "Jason King",
    "id": "10153078961444510"
  },
  "id": "585601208257495_622588581225424"
}
],
"paging": {
"cursors": {
  "before": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZAOakl3TmpVNE1UUXhOREU0TkRZANE9qRTBOalEyTkRRMU5EZAz0ZD",
  "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZAOakl5TlRnNE5UZA3hNakkxTkRJME9qRTBOalV3TnpVNE9Uaz0ZD"
}
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the name?

Comment: "not working" is not a sufficient description, please debug your code and be more specific.

Comment: @luschn its hard to debug, and i'm testing live on facebook, its just blank. or because the output is in array?

Comment: you got some output with names in a nice array, so what is the issue then?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<?php

$json='{
"data": [
{
  "from": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "id": "932242153456808"
  },
  "id": "585601208257495_620658141418468"
},
{
  "from": {
    "name": "Jason King",
    "id": "10153078961444510"
  },
  "id": "585601208257495_622535501230732"
},
{
  "from": {
    "name": "Jason King",
    "id": "10153078961444510"
  },
  "id": "585601208257495_622588581225424"
}
],
"paging": {
"cursors": {
  "before": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZAOakl3TmpVNE1UUXhOREU0TkRZANE9qRTBOalEyTkRRMU5EZAz0ZD",
  "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZAOakl5TlRnNE5UZA3hNakkxTkRJME9qRTBOalV3TnpVNE9Uaz0ZD"
}
}
}';
$res=json_decode($json,true);
$data=$res['data'];
for ($x = 0; $x <= count($data)-1; $x++) {
  echo $data[$x]['from']['name']."<br>\n";
}



?>
```

Output:

```
John Doe<br>
Jason King<br>
Jason King<br>
```